# В индексном файле не отображается кириллица

Tags: php, .htaccess

Файл `.htaccess` содержит в себе

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

На странице index.php вместо кириллицы отображаются вопросы, а на любой другой странице(даже просто скопировав содержимое и изменив название) все отображается нормально. Как это можно исправить?

Содержимое `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Магазин бытовой техники</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="registerform">
<form action="header.php" method="POST">
<p>Имя</br> <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Фамилия</br> <input type="text" name="surname"></p>
<p>Пароль</br> <input type="password" name="password"></p>
<p>Повтор параля</br> <input type="password" name="repassword"></p>
<p>Логин</br> <input type="text" name="login"></p>
<p>E-mail</br> <input type="text" name="password"></p>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Изменив кодировку в index файле на `utf-8 без BOM` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил данный файл и создал новый, который сохранил в utf-8 без BOM

Comment: Можно было и не удалять, а просто изменить кодировку через панель